# jquery: clear input of cloned element

Tags: jquery

I cloned an element and nowt I want to clear all its input values. How?

Element to clone:

```
<div id = "clone">
       <span >
            <input type = "text" >
            <input type = "text">
     </span> 
</div>
```

js:

```
new_ele = $('#clone').clone()
new_ele.find().val("")  # not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like

```
var new_ele = $('#clone').clone();
new_ele.find('input').val("");
```

Comment: Yes, putting 'input' did the trick. Not sure I get why, shouldn't find() get all descendants?

Comment: @user984003, the reason is, when you use new_ele.find(), it will return a jquery object without any element wrapping it, you should provide a selector to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var new_ele = $('#clone').clone();
$('input', new_ele).val("");
```